# How to change URL of hyperlink in gridview on RowDataBound

Tags: gridview, hyperlink, rowdatabound

I have gridview with template field that contains a hypelink. I'd like to change the URL of the hyperlink based on some logic in a specific field of my SQL data (data table bound to grid). I'm thinking I need to use the RowDataBound event, check the value of the data table's filed and set the NavigateURL as needed.

How do I access the value of the column in the data table during RowDataBound?

I can figure out if it is not a header or footer row and access the hyper link control with the code below. But drawing a blank on my logic to view the data to determine which URL to set.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HyperLink hl = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("hlStatus");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick. If there is a better way please let me know.

```
DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
int iStatusCode =  Convert.ToInt32( drv[myDatAccessLayer.Class.Property.ToString()]);
```

it gives me the value of the column I want in the current row.

Answer (score 0):

The [Eval method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx) will give you what you're after.

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        HyperLink hl = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("hlStatus");
        hl.NavigateUrl = "http://www.google.com?q=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ColumnName");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but I know how to set all the parts of the hyperlink I am trying to figure out what the underlying data of that current row's column is so I can make a decision.

The grid is bound to a DataTable that has rows. I need access to one column of that binding row so I can run if or case logic on it.

Comment: Looking closer to your solution I see you have the e.Row.DataItem on the end of the URL Kind of what I needed but not as part of the URL. Thanks none the less!